# Dropping y strip, but not x, from ggplot2 facet

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to create a 2D facet plot. I wish to drop the y-axis strip (because it is self-explanatory) but remove the x-axis strip (because it is not).

I found several examples about how to remove both strips, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547487/r-removing-facet-wrap-labels-completely-in-ggplot2). However, in every case, it was showing you how to get rid of all the labels. There is an example of [how to remove the labels from one panel and not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144182/ggplot2-and-gridextra-completely-remove-strip-in-facet-grid-not-just-invisibl), but this seems more complicated than I imagine (hope) it actually is. (Also, when I copied and pasted the code, R did not recognize the "unit" command that appeared in the code fragment, though [I see that this is addressed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885150/error-could-not-find-function-unit).)

So, let's say I have the facet grid below, and I want to hide the grey strip for `cut`, but not `color`.

```
require(ggplot2)
pdf(file = sprintf("minimal.pdf"))
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(cut ~ color, scales="fixed")
print(p)
dev.off()
```

Adding the following line turns both strips white, and removes the characters from the y-strip (cut).

```
p <- p + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())
```

That's an improvement, but what I really want to do is keep the x-strip as it was, with the original grey background, but remove the y-strip. Manually adjusting the margins every time I resize the figure, as is done in one of the references, does not seem like a nice way to do it. I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you make this reproducible with fake data?

Comment: I dont think that adding `+theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())` is that complicated... in any case if you use it often you can save it like `my.theme <- theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())` and then all you have to do is `p + my.theme`

Comment: Maloneypatr, edited to use reproducible data as requested. Konvas, I agree that this is not complicated, but it doesn't do quite the right thing (see edited question).

Answer (score 3):

You can subset the gtable to remove the column you don't want

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

strips <- subset(g$layout, grepl("strip-right", g$layout$name))

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g[,-unique(strips$r)])
```